# laravel-elixir-image-optimize has limits when optimizing too many images at the same time

Tags: javascript, image, optimization, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I was working with laravel 5.4 and has a plan to optimize the images of the project.

I tried use laravel-elixir-image-optimize, the laravel-elixir package to do the job. But in my case, I have around **1000 images** in the folder but when I run the task, it only processes about **100 images** and then stops.

Has anyone ever seen the similar situation?